# Posting data to server and response is :{"Message":"An error has occurred."}

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, http-post

I have tried many methods of posting data to server but none of them worked and only response am getting is:

> {"Message":"An error has occurred."}

Below is the method I've tried recently.

```
NSString *cust_id=@"2";
NSString *Prod_ID=@"18";
NSString *Vend_ID=@"1";
NSString *Quant=@"2";
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"customerid=%@&productid=%@&vendorid=%@&quantity=%@",cust_id,Prod_ID,Vend_ID,Quant];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dealnxt.com/api/addtocart"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"str:%@",str);
```

Comment: Contact the server developers and ask them to provide better error messages.

Comment: @rmaddy everything is fixed from server side

Comment: This is server side error, try post the request with postman first to see if it error or not, beside, i think it should be `NSUTF8StringEncoding` instead of `NSASCIIStringEncoding`

Comment: @Tj3n Hey ! this answer was helpful, it solved my query :) thanks a lot

Comment: @Shikha, your error message is come from web service side please check and make sure you are passing right parameters. Thanks

Comment: @Tj3n vote up question such that further people will be helped and thanks a lot for you help.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You @Tj3N, your answer was helpful.

Just needed to change encoding type. From NSASCIIStringEncoding to NSUTF8StringEncoding.
Below is the Updated code.

```
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"customerid=%@&productid=%@&vendorid=%@&quantity=%@",cid,PID,VID,QQ];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"str:%@",str);
```

Answer (score 0):

**BASE_URL = PASS_YOUR_URL
  _params = parameters // AS NSMutableDictionary**  Try this.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
 [params setValue:YOUR_VALUE forKey:@"cust_id"]; // here pass your field that you want to pass as parameter. 
 [params setValue:YOUR_VALUE forKey:@"Prod_ID"];

 NSString *url = [BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:_action];

 AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
 manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
 manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];
[manager POST:url parameters:_params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"response = %@", responseObject);
        if( _success )
        {
            _success( responseObject ) ;
        }
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
            NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
            if( _failure )
            {
                _failure( error) ;
            }
}];
```

Comment: No, you do not need `AFNetworking`. It's helpful but not required.

Comment: @rmaddy then what is problem ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya We don't know since the OP hasn't told us what the problem is. The server is returning a useless error message. Until the OP finds out what the actual server error is, there is no way to know what is wrong with the posted code. Simply suggesting that the OP replace their code with `AFNetworking` won't fix anything.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Having said that, it is possible that your code fixes the problem. But that doesn't mean you need `AFNetworking`. The OP simply needs to fix whatever bug is in their existing code.

Comment: @rmaddy ok brother .

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the data in query string where as the data which you want to post should be passed as NSDictionary object converted to Data.