# post parameter to sever using dictionary swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I am trying to send data to the server using a dictionary but unfortunately the data is not saving to the database (fields were found to be blank) and I am getting the below response:

> Optional(["status": true, "msg": successfull])

And also tried to show `UIActivityIndicator` to user until he got a response but couldn't find a way.

Code attempted:

```
let dict = [ "key_one": self.tf1.text!,"key_two":self.tf2.text!]

    do {

        let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: .PrettyPrinted)

        // create post request
        let url = NSURL(string: "myAPIUrl.php?")!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        // insert json data to the request
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.HTTPBody = jsonData

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data, response, error in
            if error != nil{
                print("Error -> \(error)")
                return
            }

            do {
                let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]

                print("Response -> \(result)")

            } catch {
                print("Inside Error Section -> \(error)")
            }
        }

        task.resume()

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: key_one is your database table field ?

Comment: yes `key_one` is related to my database, in fact all keys.

Comment: key_one  and key_two both are field and what is query in .php file

Comment: `key_one and key_two both are field` mean ?

Comment: that both are field in your  table . ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41255269/6656894 refer this answer that you get idea about how to pass parameter into server database and its in objective c

Comment: yes both are fields related, @HimanshuMoradiya i knew how to handle this situation in `objective c` fairly can you please suggest swift code for that :)

Comment: ya i can post swift code also if you want

Comment: sure, i will appreciate that if you suggest with handling `UIActivityIndicator` also.

Comment: ok wait i will updated as soon as possible

Comment: I suggest to "echo" request from your server API file link [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103528/swift-httppost-data-not-inserting-to-mysql-database)

Comment: I suggest to "echo" request from your server API file like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103528/swift-httppost-data-not-inserting-to-mysql-database).

Comment: @Dikula thanks for your concern :), i already found a way to insert data inside database using post request. Actually i am finding a another way using dict.

Comment: I suggest to "echo" request with your server API file like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103528/swift-httppost-data-not-inserting-to-mysql-database).

Answer (score 4):

// write this in one fucantion

```
 let Username:NSString = EmailTextField.text! as NSString
 let password:NSString = PasswordTextField.text! as NSString


 let headers = [
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "postman-token": "121b2f04-d2a4-72b7-a93f-98e3383f9fa0"
        ]
 let parameters = [
            "username": "\(Username)",
            "password": "\(password)"
        ]

 if let postData = (try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])) {

        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "YOUR_URL_HERE")!,
                                              cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                              timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        request.httpBody = postData

        let session = URLSession.shared

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
               (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil) {
                    print(error)
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                      if let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])) as? NSDictionary
                        {
                            let success = json["status"] as? Int
                            let message = json["message"] as? String
                            // here you check your success code.
                            if (success == 1)
                            {
                                print(message)
                                let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image],  applicationActivities: [])
                                 present(vc, animated: true)
                            }
                            else
                            {

                               // print(message)
                            }

                        }

                    })
                }
            }

            task.resume()
        }
```

Comment: I dont know why down voted my ques without reason, Okay let me try with this code and catch you back.

Comment: is it `UIActivityViewController` or `UIActivityIndicator` ?

Comment: now in this code i did not use nay activityindicatorcontroller beacuse first you have to check that this code working fine for you or not ? if yes then you can impliment UIActivityViewController

Comment: sure i am doing plus one for your time. I genuinely asked a ques which doesn't mean whether suggested code is working or not which mean how it is working and goes also as per the op's query.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started    @vaibhav refer this link for  URLSession information howz it work.

Comment: and ya this code now i m using in my project so i can post you for your solution.

Comment: thanks, let me try this completely converting your ans in swift2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131492/discussion-between-vaibhav-and-himanshu-moradiya).