# Why my parameters isn't to add URLString in post method in AFNetworking 3.0?

Tags: ios, post, parameters, swift3, afnetworking

My response data isn't to come with parameters.

I used to do it this way which worked:

```
let str = "https://itunes.apple.com/in/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=2/json"

let dict = ["user":"admin"]

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: str)!)

request.httpMethod = "POST"

 let afManager = AFHTTPSessionManager()

 afManager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()

 afManager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()

 afManager.requestSerializer.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

afManager.requestSerializer.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


 afManager.post(str, parameters: dict, progress: nil, success: { (dataTask, responsedata) in

       print(responsedata)

     }) { (dataTask, err) in

          print(error)

       }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41328809/6656894 refer this answer

Comment: I think you need to convert response data to JSON format.

Comment: What response do you get, and what did you expect?