# Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking-3

I am using `AFNetworking` to interact with server.
In **postman** I am getting **response** as **success** but using `AFnetworking` getting **error** as :

```
status code: 500, headers
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
Connection = close;
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
Date = "Tue, 24 Jan 2017 06:39:01 GMT";
Server = "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)";
```

Below is my code for reference:

```
 AFNetworkReachabilityManager *reachabilityManager = [AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager];


if(![reachabilityManager isReachable])
{
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Network not available." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    return;
}
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSLog(@"userid:%@",[userDefaults valueForKey:@"user_id"]);

NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"5",@"customer_id",@"5885e8968fa4293d182ad0a1",@"id[]",nil]; //2

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];


NSString *str =@"http://xxx/yyy/customer/";
NSString *strURl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@assets/deleteElement",str];

NSLog(@"url:%@\n %@",strURl,dict);

[APP_DELEGATE showLoading:self];
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                               options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted 
                                                     error:&error];

if (! jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
} else {
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"json:%@",jsonString);
}


[manager POST:strURl parameters:dict progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"response: %@", responseObject);
     [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [APP_DELEGATE removeLoading];
     });


 } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.debugDescription);
 }];
```

Any help to solve this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41255269/6656894 refer this answer

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya tried above link but no change same error I am getting.

Comment: brother try your url request with other tools like post man and check did you get response from api ? or not because your error shows that there is not api found in your server so .

Comment: just serialised request and response like this `manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];` and
`manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];`.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya in postman getting response as success as mentioned in question.

Comment: manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];  
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"]; Check this serialize in your code

Comment: @JayeshThanki already added please check question.

Comment: @user2931321 try my suggestion change your Serialize

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya tried your suggestion but same error..

Comment: @user2931321 update your question with that code and also error log

Comment: already added please check once again

Comment: manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil]; add this line and i did not see your updated question. so update it

Comment: added now Iam getting 500 error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133857/discussion-between-himanshu-moradiya-and-user2931321).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

404 is file not found. recheck if api is post or get or u should check this 2 only.

```
      NSString *str =@"http://api.beyondchange.in/api/customer/";
      NSString *strURl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/assets/deleteElement",str];
```

OR

```
  manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
```

Comment: try this :-
   manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];